# CodePipeline taking wrong artifacts?

Tags: .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

So really quick. I have a CodePipeline that deploys my .NET API to an EB and all of that is good. The only problem is that the CodeBuid doesn't send the good folder to the Pipeline. It keeps sending the root folder. If anyone can help me out with this I'd be really grateful since it's probably really simple. This is how my buildspec.yml file looks like:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - dotnet restore
      - dotnet build
  build:
    commands:
      - dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -o ./output --self-contained false
      - ls
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: ./output
```

The 'ls' command is there because I wanted to check that the output folder is created as it should be - and the answer is yes it is...

Answer (score 0):

Every path is relative so there is never a need for the ./ notation.

This should work:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'output/**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
```

or

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: output
```

Comment: I killed my EB environment and ran it again and it worked like a charm even with the ./